# Facebook messenger is not asking "Draw over other app" permission on marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

On Marshmallow, on fresh app launch, Facebook Messenger is not asking for a "Draw over other app" permission and still messenger can draw the chat head or bubble on other apps, how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of google are not clear in that point they say that android.permissions.System_Alert_Window is a signature premission so its granted by default on instalation but only if you install from PlayStore the apk instalation need to request permission, but also say that System_Alert_Window is special permission and needs to ask for that.
You can see that here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview